# how to run cakephp application on xampp

Tags: cakephp

i am new to CakePHP, i have configured cakephp on Xampp it's working perfectly.

my folder structure is :

To make it run cakephp I have updated the document root directory(c:/xampp/hdocs/cakephp/app/webroot) in Http.conf which is located in apache conf folder

then i started apache cakephp framework worked out . browser shown a home page

**i try to run Simple cakephp example application**

```
   c:/xampp/hdocs/polls/app/webroot
```

In the same manner i have configured cakephp example application on xampp and i have also updated the http.conf .  But it's not working ,when i run the server simply showing blank page in browser  .

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post you apache error log somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the path you provided above in your browser then you are just viewing that directory location in your browser.

You need to go through your local apache webserver by entering a local host url or any alias you may have setup.

```
http://localhost/<cakePHP app name>/<controller>/<action>/
```

if you want to go to the root cakephp app then it would be

```
http://localhost/<cakephp app name>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope somebody finds it useful...

> cakephp_3_x-x
>
> xampp v 3.2.1

PART 1   (to test that cakePHP is working at all, using cakePHP included server)

Create the DB following the cakePHP tutor

In bake.bat -- add php path:

```
J:\xampp\php\php "%lib%cake.php" %*
```

DOS prompt:

```
  J:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-3-1-6>.\bin\cake bake all users
  J:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-3-1-6>.\bin\cake bake all bookmarks
  J:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-3-1-6>.\bin\cake bake all tags
```

cmd> cd J:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-3-1-6

```
  J:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-3-1-6>set PATH=%PATH%;J:\xampp\php\;
  J:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-3-1-6>bin\cake server
```

to look at it http://localhost:8765/

PART 2        (for example, if we have port 8787 free to use for virtual host)

Repeat (for J:\xampp\apps\bookmarker)

In bake.bat -- add php path:

```
  J:\xampp\php\php "%lib%cake.php" %*
```

DOS prompt:

```
  J:\xampp\apps\bookmarker>.\bin\cake bake all users
  J:\xampp\apps\bookmarker>.\bin\cake bake all bookmarks
  J:\xampp\apps\bookmarker>.\bin\cake bake all tags

  J:\xampp\htdocs\applications.html (create your own application section...:
          <!-- START cakephp-3-0-0 bookmarker -->
          <div align="center" class="module_table">
  )
  ...
  <div align="right" class="module_access"><a target="_blank" name="bookmarker" href="http://localhost:8787/bookmarks">Access</a></div>
  ...
```

1) main httpd.conf.

```
  Listen 8787

  <VirtualHost *:8787>
  DocumentRoot "J:\xampp\apps\bookmarker"
  # ServerName www.example.com
     <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
     <Directory "J:\xampp\apps\bookmarker" >
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>

  # Other directives here
  </VirtualHost>
```

DO not include application specific config for apache:

```
  # Include "J:/xampp/apps/bookmarker/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

2) key: for css to work: in webroot/.htaccess

```
  #<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #    RewriteEngine On
  #    ## RewriteBase J:\xampp\apps\bookmarker\src\
  #    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  #</IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
  </IfModule>
```

The rest is as installed by cakePHP bake to try either through xampp application interface or directly:

```
  http://localhost:8787/bookmarks
```